# Encode writeablebitmap into jpeg then into base64string

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, filestream

I am building a surface-rt app that takes a picture which results into a stream and a WriteableBitmap [as this example shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx)  I then encode the stream into a Base64String and pass it to a WebApi service where I store it in a server.

The same sample page suggests to encode the image into jpeg before saving as the resulting file will be quite large, now my question is can I/Should I encode the stream/writeableBitMap 
before enconding it into a base64string to reduce the traffic to the webapi service.

Disclaimer: I have very little experience handling images, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very large question. In general reducing the amount of data you are sending over the wire is good. However, if your requirement is to preserve a high quality image then using a lossy jpeg compression would be undesirable.

Comment: I am really just trying to keep a good quality image not necessarily crazy good quality, I tried saving the stream to a PNG (Which was around 8MB( put it in paint and saved as JPEG and it came down to 900KB  with little quality loss. That's why I started looking into encoding to JPEG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method described in the link you shared seems like the right approach for compressing a `WriteableBitmap`. You do want to compress the captured image to make it smaller. The only remaining part is encoding it as Base64 which you can do using [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The one thing I would consider is to use something like [`BackgroundUploader.CreateUploadFromStreamAsync()`](http://BackgroundUploader.CreateUploadFromStreamAsync) to upload the stream. In that case you might not want to do the Base64 encoding part on the client side, but perhaps do it on the server instead. I'm not an http expert, but Base64 makes your data larger and I'd suspect there might be faster ways to upload bits these days than using Base64 and also your Base64-encoded string might end up being Base64-encoded twice - making the transmitted data larger yet.

Comment: I tried several times to use the approach in that example, but I can't  ever come up with a smaller stream. It feels pretty dumb to say but the streams ends up being/looking the same size as before it went through the encoder. I don't know what I need to keep as the 'encoded' data, the 'stream' in the example looks exactly the same as the stream before.
 I am doing it as Base64 to make it easier to send to my webservice

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked how that sample captures the photo. If you are using `CameraCaptureUI.CaptureFileAsync()` then that obviously captures to a file already compressed. If you used `MediaCapture` and `CaptureElement` you get the [`CapturePhotoToStreamAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700840.aspx) method which captures to a stream, but that also seems to support compression, though it does seem to skip disk I/O which you might not need. The example you linked shows how to save the data from a `WriteableBitmap` which has an uncompressed pixel array.

Comment: In short - I'd recommend to transmit the captured compressed image stream over the wire and handle BASE64 encoding on the service end.